# Update a row in mysql and drop the row if it creates a duplicate as defined by the unique key

Tags: mysql

I've got a MySQL table that has a lot of entries. Its got a unique key defined as (state, source) so there are no duplicates for that combination of columns. However now I am realizing that much of the state data is not entered consistently. For example in some rows it is entered as "CA" and others it might be spelled out as "California."

I'd like to update all the entries that say "California" to be "CA" and if it creates a conflict in the unique key, drop the row. How can I do that?

Comment: can you do a 
    select count(source),'CA', source from tblname where state in    ('California','CA') group by 'CA', source having count(source) > 1 

to get an idea of how many potential conflicts you have?   may be easier to deal with these by hand if there aren't many.

Answer (score 1):

You may be better off dumping your data and using an external tool like [Google Refine](http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/) to clean it up. Look at using foreign keys in the future to avoid these issues.

Comment: Dont think this is a good solution because data is still be entered into the database. My thought was to create a script that periodically went through and standardized the entries for states

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in one SQL statement. And if you have foreign key relationships from other tables to the one you are trying to clean-up then you definitely do *not* want to do this in one step (even if you could).

```
CREATE TABLE state_mappings (
    `old` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    `new` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO state_mappings VALUES ('California', 'CA'), ...;

INSERT IGNORE INTO MyTable (state, source)
    SELECT sm.new, s.source from states s JOIN state_mappings sm
        ON s.state = sm.old;

// Update tables with foreign keys here

DELETE FROm MyTable WHERE state IN (SELECT distinct old FROM state_mappings);
DROP TABLE state_mappings;
```

I'm no SQL pro, so these statements can probably be optimized, but you get the gist.